# Determination of radius based on data points

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, regions, geometry

I have some data points:

```
A=Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
  Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6rlR.png"],"Byte"]]]]

B=Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
  Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/jylyd.png"],"Byte"]]]]
```

If `A` and `B` are $\color{blue}{\text{joined}}$ and plotted in graphic to be below

[image]

My questions:

1. How to determine the value of both radius or diameter of circles?
2. How to determine the distance between circle 1 and circle 2?

Answer (score 5):

```
d = {#1^2, #1, #2, #2^2} & @@@ A;
lm = LinearModelFit[d, {1, a, b, c}, {a, b, c}]
ex = lm["BestFitParameters"].{1, x^2, x, y} - y^2
ru = CoefficientRules[ex]
c0 = {0, 0}
r0 = Sqrt[{0, 0} /. ru]
d2 = {#1^2, #1, #2, #2^2} & @@@ B;
lm2 = LinearModelFit[d2, {1, a, b, c}, {a, b, c}]
x1 = ({1, 0} /. cr)/2
c1 = {x1, 0}
r1 = ({0, 0} /. cr) + x0^2 // Sqrt
ListPlot[{A, B}, 
 Epilog -> {Dashed, Circle[c0, r0], Circle[c1, r1], Red, 
   PointSize[0.02], Point[{c0, c1}], Blue, Arrowheads[{-0.05, 0.05}], 
   Arrow[{c0, c1}], Text[x1, (c0 + c1)/2, {0, -1}]}]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think the OP try to know the two radius form `RandomSample[Join[A, B]]` but not from `A` then `B`

Comment: @yode the 2 radii are in the text that follows the image with the centers preceding.

Answer (score 3):

Well,a method based on *Image Processing* strik to my mind.Let do it.

Build a image for your data

```
pos = Join[A, B];
bound = MinMax /@ Transpose[pos];
bin = ReplaceImageValue[
  ConstantImage[0, Ceiling[Subtract @@@ (Reverse /@ bound)]], 
  TranslationTransform[-First /@ bound][pos] -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Do a `DistanceTransform` in `bin` and get what your are after

```
ImageAdjust[dist = DistanceTransform[FillingTransform[Dilation[bin, 1]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
TakeLargest[Flatten[ImageData[dist]], 2]
```

> `{92.0054, 92.0054}`

And I think if your are in the 11.2 comming up,[`RegionImage`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/RegionImage.html) will make your life be easer when you build that `bin`.

Comment: +1 Neat! Learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks for kind word..

Answer (score 3):

**Using `CirclePoints`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"]
A = Uncompress[
   FromCharacterCode[
    Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6rlR.png"], 
      "Byte"]]]];
B = Uncompress[
   FromCharacterCode[
    Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/jylyd.png"], 
      "Byte"]]]];
```

It would be simpler to do this with presented and separated data such `A` and `B`, so to make it more general and interesting, shuffle these points together and visualize:

```
apts = RandomSample[A, Length@A];
bpts = RandomSample[B, Length@B];
pts = Join[apts, bpts];

ListLinePlot[pts, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Take any three points at a time from the shuffled set and generate many (say `100`) circles. Later, select the two commonest circles after appropriate rounding.

```
circs = Table[CircleThrough[RandomChoice[pts, 3]], 100];

circsSel = (GatherBy[
      circs, {Round[Last@#, 0.01], Round[First@#, 0.01]} &]) // 
    MaximalBy[#, Length, 2] & // Map[Round[#, 0.001] &, #, {3}] & // 
  Map[Commonest]
```

> {{Circle[{0., 0.}, 90.92]}, {Circle[{123., 0.}, 90.92]}}

The distance between corresponding circles is:

```
EuclideanDistance @@ RegionCentroid @@@ circsSel
```

> 123. 

Answer (score 3):

Direct minimization using RegionDistance:

```
A = Uncompress[
   FromCharacterCode[
    Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6rlR.png"], 
      "Byte"]]]];

B = Uncompress[
   FromCharacterCode[
    Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/jylyd.png"], 
      "Byte"]]]];

circles[{x1_?NumericQ, y1_, r1_}, {x2_, y2_, r2_}, pts_] := Total[
  RegionDistance[
    RegionUnion[Circle[{x1, y1}, r1], Circle[{x2, y2}, r2]],
    pts
    ]^2
  ]

FindMinimum[
 circles[{x1, y1, r1}, {x2, y2, r2}, Join[A, B]],
 {{x1, 0}, {y1, 0}, {r1, 100}, {x2, 120}, {y2, 0}, {r2, 100}}
 ]
```

> {8.19407*10^-6, {x1 -> 6.74579*10^-8, y1 -> -7.44746*10^-9,
> r1 -> 90.92, x2 -> 123., y2 -> -7.48226*10^-9, r2 -> 90.92}}

Answer (score 2):

Denote $f(x_i,y_i)=(x_i-x_0)^2+(y_i-y_0)^2$ a squared distance from a data point $(x_i,y_i)$ to the supposed circle center $(x_0,y_0)$. The idea is like this: values of $|f(x_i,y_i)-f(x_j,y_j)|$ or $(f(x_i,y_i)-f(x_j,y_j))^2$ should be small if $(x_0,y_0)$ is at the same distance from all $(x_i,y_i)$. For example one can minimize function
$$
g(x_0,y_0)=\sum_{i=2}^n(f(x_{i},y_{i})-f(x_{i-1},y_{i-1}))^2
$$
wrt $(x_0,y_0)$.

```
f[x_, y_] = ((x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2);
distsqrd = f @@@ A;
g = Total@(ListConvolve[{-1, 1}, distsqrd]^2);
```

Minimizing $g$:

```
minA = NMinimize[g, {x0, y0}]
```

> {0.01583549,{x0->0.000013,y0->-9.5718009*10^-10}}

Now taking the mean value of distances obtained gives

```
rA = Mean[(distsqrd /. minA[[2]])^(1/2)]
```

> 90.9200011

The same procedure for `B` gives

```
minB
```

> {0.61139090, {x0 -> 123.000010, 
>     y0 -> 1.2381995*10^-15}}

```
rB
```

> 90.9200036

The distance between the circle centers is

```
Norm[({x0, y0} /. minA[[2]]) - ({x0, y0} /. minB[[2]])]
```

> 122.99999706

Answer (score 2):

```
A = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6rlR.png"], 
  "Byte"]]]];
B = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/jylyd.png"], 
  "Byte"]]]];
data = Join[A, B];

f[c1_, c2_, p_] := Min[Abs[(p[[1]] - c1[[1]])^2 + (p[[2]] - c1[[2]])^2 - c1[[3]]^2], Abs[(p[[1]] - c2[[1]])^2 + (p[[2]] - c2[[2]])^2 - c2[[3]]^2]]
obj = Sum[f[{x1, y1, r1}, {x2, y2, r2}, data[[k]]], {k, 1, Length[data]}];
sol = Quiet@NMinimize[{obj, Abs[r1 - r2] > 100}, {x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

c1 = ((x - x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2 - r1^2) /. sol[[2]]
c2 = ((x - x2)^2 + (y - y2)^2 - r2^2) /. sol[[2]]

gr1 = ListPlot[data, Axes -> False]
gr2 = ContourPlot[c1 == 0, {x, -100, 250}, {y, -150, 150}, ContourStyle -> {Dashed, Red}];
gr3 = ContourPlot[c2 == 0, {x, -100, 250}, {y, -150, 150}, ContourStyle -> {Dashed, Red}];
Show[gr1, gr2, gr3]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How to solve this depends on what you're willing/able to assume.

If we assume that you have two overlapping circles of the same radius and the line two centers of the circle have the same vertical coordinate, then the following works:

```
circles = Join[A, B];
x = MinMax[circles[[All, 1]]];
y = MinMax[circles[[All, 2]]];
radius = Differences[y]/2
(* {90.92} *)
distance = Differences[x] - 2*radius
(* {123.} *)
```

If the two centers have different vertical coordinates, then one can figure out the angle of rotation, unrotate, and apply the code above.